# How to copy files from dependencies to projects build directory?

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java Project Created, which uses some dependencies and these dependencies contains "jsp files" under folder name "Views/{Dependency Name}". I want to copy all such Views Folder to Projects Build/Views/{Dependency Name} folder using ant targets.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for the Ant copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), specifically "Copy a directory to another directory"?